# Write csv file at server-side, and send it to silverlight client via WCF RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, file, wcf-ria-services

I have created csv file at server-side. Now I want to send it to my silverlight client
via WCF RIA Services. I created the following:

```
public byte[] GetMyCSV()
{
  string file = @"c:\test.csv";
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, true, Encoding.GetEncoding(932)))
  {
    //write csv file content
    ...
  }

  ???
}
```

Should my service send byte array? If then how to get byte array from StreamWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, the [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) class if for writing to a file. As long as i understand your question you want to read from the File.

The easiest way to read all bytes from a file is to use the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx) class and the [ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) method.

```
public byte[] GetMyCSV(){
  string file = @"c:\test.csv";
  bytes[] fileBytes;

  using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))  {
    fileBytes = fileStream.ReadAllBytes();
  }

  return fileBytes;
}
```

The other way is to use the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) class, to read blocks of bytes from the file and to define additional encodings for reading.